# Возможно ли создать SWIG обёртку возвращающую классы другой обёртки?

Tags: python, c++, swig

Есть библиотека `A` на `C++`, для неё добрые люди сделали `SWIG` обёртку для `Python`, назовём её `_a`. Я пишу на плюсах библиотечку `B`, которая работает с классами из `A`. Я тоже создаю `SWIG` обёртку `_b`. Теперь, я хочу, что бы моя обёртка, могла возвращать классы обёртки `_a`,  а не  `<Swig Object of type 'MyAwesomeClass *' at 0x000001DA54B82060>`. Возможно ли такое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как выяснилось, - Да, возможно. Всё, что нужно сделать, это подключить необходимый интерфейсный файл. В моём случае это выглядело примерно так:

```
%module b

%include a.i
%import a.i

%{
    #include <A.hxx>
    #include "../B.hxx"
%}

%include "../B.hxx"
```

Вот так взлетело. В `Python` теперь корректно возвращаются объекты из подключенной обёртки.